# JSON / Java / Twilio response: "No 'To' number is specified" when request sent from JSON

Tags: java, android, json, twilio

Whatever I try, twilio is not accepting my JSON request for making a call. I keep getting "No 'To' number is specified". I am sending this from Java. And we intentionally didn't want to use Twilio Rest library.

**JSON Response:**
{"code":21201, "message":"No 'To' number is specified", "more_info":"https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21201", "status":400}

**JSON Request object**
{"Url":"http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=%3CResponse%3E%3CSay+voice%3D%22alice%22+language%3D%22en-IN%22%3EImportant+alert%3APlease+check+your+SMS%3C%2FSay%3E%3C%2FResponse%3E","To":"%2B919900299477","From":"%2B919900299477","Method":"POST","FallbackMethod":"POST","StatusCallbackMethod":"POST","Record":"false"}

**Here's the source code:**

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("Url", "http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=" + URLEncoder.encode(
                    "<Response><Say voice=\"alice\" language=\"en-IN\">"
                    + psMessage + "</Say></Response>", "UTF-8"));
jsonObject.put("To", URLEncoder.encode(psNumberToCall, "UTF-8"));
jsonObject.put("From", URLEncoder.encode("+919988776655", "UTF-8"));
jsonObject.put("Method", "POST");
jsonObject.put("FallbackMethod", "POST");
jsonObject.put("StatusCallbackMethod", "POST");
jsonObject.put("Record", "false");

Log.i(getClass().getName(), "JSON Object: " + jsonObject.toString());

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
String sUrl = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC****/Calls.json";
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(sUrl);
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
httpPost.setEntity(se);
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
String authString = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString 
      ((ACCOUNT_SID + ":" + AUTH_TOKEN).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", authString);

Log.i(getClass().getName(), "HttpPost: " + httpPost.toString());

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
InputStream is = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
StringBuilder sbResp = new StringBuilder();
String sLine = "";
while((sLine = br.readLine()) != null){
    sbResp.append(sLine);
}
is.close();
return sbResp;
```

Answer (score 3):

I could solve this myself. Posting it for the benefit of others in case if they face the same problem:

The request is simple post method. Response can be JSON / XML etc.,

Here's the working code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(sTwilioUrl);

List<NameValuePair> paramsList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
paramsList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", psNumberToCall));
paramsList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", "+919988776655"));
paramsList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Url", sVoiceUrl));

httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(paramsList));
//httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
//httpPost.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
String authString = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString
        ((ACCOUNT_SID + ":" + AUTH_TOKEN).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", authString);

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
return EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
```

Comment: In my case the issue was related to the authentication not being properly encoded. The error is totally misleading and unfortunately the documentation doesn't help much. However I got some ideas based on your answer. Thanks.